# "Authorization is required to perform that Action" Error on a copy of existing code that works

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Apps Script and the OAuth2 for Apps Script Library to connect to a couple Google advertising platforms. Basically, each account team has a Google sheet that automatically gets their campaign data every morning. I've got a couple of these sheets up and running already, but when I try to set up this most recent sheet I'm getting the "Authorization is required to perform that Action" at the very end of the OAuth process. I'm able to start the OAuth dialogue, select an account to authorize, but then I run into the error.

I authorized the script in the script editor before I ran it, and all of my OAuth credentials are correct. I've even deleted and re-created the scripts. The other sheets running the same scripts are still working fine.

What's going on here? I'd appreciate any ideas, I've set up a couple test sheets to see if I can puzzle it out, and now they're all returning the same error.

Update: Everything works properly when run from a different account, so it's looking like it's a problem with my account, specifically. Is there any way to manually check that an Apps Script project has been authorized correctly on a given account, aside from the prompt when the script is first created?

Comment: A copy of an existing script is not that existing script - you must reauthorize every new script. Did you authorize the script you are running? i.e. if in the script editor you write a function `function foo() {/* foo intentionally does nothing */}` and run it, does it ask you to authenticate? Who are the scripts being run as? Without seeing even a mockup of your code, I'm not sure what we can do to help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I've reauthorized the new script and set up all the OAuth credentials correctly - got a coworker to test it from their account and it worked fine - looks like it's a problem with my account, specifically. Going to edit the post now, and I'd appreciate any help, but it looks like this isn't actually a coding issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by explicitly setting the Authorization Scopes in the manifest. In case anyone finds this question later, here's the links to the relevant Apps Script guides:

Authorization Scopes:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

List of OAuth 2.0 Scopes:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes